# Is there problem with my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote HTML table in which i have checkbox for every row. So now i want to add checkbox in my header which will check all check boxes in the table. I have done it, but it does not work. Any idea?

```
<table class="table table-hover table-inbox">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" id="allmsgs">
            </th>
            <th>Sender</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Last Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="1" class="i-checks msg">
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">Jeremy Massey</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></td>
            <td class="mail-date"><a href="#">12/12/2019 15:35</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="unread active">
            <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="2" class="i-checks msg">
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">Marshall Horne</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Praesent nec nisl sed neque ornare maximus at ac enim.</a></td>
            <td class="mail-date">12/12/2019 15:35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="3" class="i-checks msg">
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">Grant Franco</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Etiam maximus tellus a turpis tempor mollis.</a></td>
            <td class="mail-date">12/12/2019 15:35</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have also javascript function ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#allmsgs').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('.msg').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            });
        } else {
            $('.msg').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

which is located in my `scripts.js` file and this one is linked with html (link is not the problem because other functions are working.

Comment: "but it does not work" meaning what, exactly? I mean, do you have errors on the console, for example?

Comment: when i check the checkbox in thead, it does not check all in tbody

Comment: Have you also linked to a copy of jQuery? That code won't work without it, and there's no mention you're using jQuery in your question/tags.

Comment: Define "does not work".  In what way does it fail?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  When you use the browser's script debugger, do your jQuery selectors find the element(s) you expect?  What does the code do when you debug?

Comment: i already have a jQuery library.
http://facility-management.devsolution.mk/account/all-messages.html

Comment: @MartinM: The element being clicked on your page is *not* an `<input type="checkbox">` as shown in the code here.  It would appear that you have other code which is replacing that element with something else.  So your click event isn't being triggered.  Consult the documentation for whatever plugin you're using and how to respond to events.

Comment: Your method can be as simple as `$('#allmsgs').click(function() { $('.msg').prop('checked', this.checked); })` no need for the repeated code or loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you add the `jquery` library :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#allmsgs').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('.msg').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
            });
        } else {
            $('.msg').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-inbox">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" id="allmsgs">
            </th>
            <th>Sender</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Last Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="1" class="i-checks msg">
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">Jeremy Massey</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></td>
            <td class="mail-date"><a href="#">12/12/2019 15:35</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="unread active">
            <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="2" class="i-checks msg">
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">Marshall Horne</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Praesent nec nisl sed neque ornare maximus at ac enim.</a></td>
            <td class="mail-date">12/12/2019 15:35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">
                <input type="checkbox" name="3" class="i-checks msg">
            </td>
            <td><a href="#">Grant Franco</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Etiam maximus tellus a turpis tempor mollis.</a></td>
            <td class="mail-date">12/12/2019 15:35</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I already have a linked jQuery library... but still not work online
`<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`

http://facility-management.devsolution.mk/account/all-messages.html

Comment: @MartinM it literally works in the link you're provided. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome... Version 79.0.3945.79 and i also try on Edge but same

Comment: I see your problem, I try to find the problem cant promise anything

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.checked)` inside the each ? check if it logs anything

Comment: it does not log nothing in console

Comment: as it doesn't log anything, the function is not run at all or it can't find any element with that classname

Comment: i found some script that i think makes problem...
```
(function ($) {
 "use strict";
 
  $('.i-checks').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
  radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
 });
 
 
 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204493/discussion-between-jbadminton-and-martin-m).

Answer (score -1):

From the site you linked the clicked element is

```
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
```

Try, setting the id `allmsgs` to it instead of the input, if it is exposed in the html.